# parent ul not expanding to content

Tags: jquery, css

The green ul is not expanding to float left the two blue li's. The absolute for the green is causing my grief on the height not covering its nested elements.  How can i get past this so the green background expands to cover its children? I would like to keep this as straight css but if jquery will do the trick im interested. http://jsfiddle.net/B34AU/

```
ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    background: red;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 10px;
}
li  ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
li > ul > li {
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}

li > ul > li > ul {
    background: #cc0000;
    display:block;
}

li > ul > li > ul > li {
    background: #cc0000;
    display:block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```
   <ul>
    <li>
        1
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">1.1</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">1.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1.1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1.1.3</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        2
        <ul>
            <li>2.1</li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        3
        <ul>
            <li>3.1</li>
            <li>3.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Better use children selectors (`>`) instead of descendant ones, which are slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed these CSS lines and its working fine as expected.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/B34AU/1/)**

Changed these CSS

```
li > ul > li {
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /*Added this line*/
}

li > ul > li > ul {
    background: #cc0000;
    display:block;
    position: static;/*Added this line*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expand `<ul>` independently of the number of children, you can use

```
li > ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
li > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3aVEC/1/)

Comment: this works for the width but now if i want to add a nested ul within 1.1 so there is 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3 etc the height is just adding scrollers?

Comment: @user520300 Use `li > ul { overflow: visible; }` instead of `auto`. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3aVEC/2/)

Comment: almost.  I have 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3 etc not floating they are just going straight down under 1.1 etc.  If the green background height could expand to cover all the nesting that would be what im looking for http://jsfiddle.net/B34AU/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B34AU/  see the fiddle, if the green height could expand to cover the nesting we're gold

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3aVEC/)

You need to set a `width`:

```
width: 440px;
```

Just use the following formula

```
numChilds * (marginLeft + borderLeft + paddingLeft + width + paddingRight + borderRigth + marginRigth)
= 2 * (10+0+0+200+0+0+10)
= 2 * 220
= 440
```

Comment: is there a way that the green expands or contracts based on the number of subs?  lets say there is three under 1, one under 2, and two under three?